# How to display different messages on whiptail progress bar along with progress bar?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, whiptail

I am trying to use "whiptail" to display progress to users while removing some RPM's. Using

```
{
 echo 25
 yum remove package_name
 echo 50
 yum remove package_name
 echo 75 
 yum remove package_name
 echo 100
 sleep 1

} | whiptail --gauge "Removing RPM's" 6 60 0*
```

[image: This is how it looks like]

What i would like is to display message "Removing package_name" along with the progress bar, Like when redhat installs packages
[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doR0x.png)
How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 5):

Whiptail uses a weird syntax to update the gauge text. Have a look at the following script :

```
#!/bin/bash
{
    sleep 0.5
    echo -e "XXX\n0\nyum remove package_0... \nXXX"
    sleep 2
    echo -e "XXX\n25\nyum remove package_0... Done.\nXXX"
    sleep 0.5

    echo -e "XXX\n25\nyum remove package_1... \nXXX"
    sleep 2
    echo -e "XXX\n50\nyum remove package_1... Done.\nXXX"
    sleep 0.5

    echo -e "XXX\n50\nyum remove package_2... \nXXX"
    sleep 2
    echo -e "XXX\n75\nyum remove package_2... Done.\nXXX"
    sleep 0.5

    echo -e "XXX\n75\nyum remove package_3... \nXXX"
    sleep 2
    echo -e "XXX\n100\nyum remove package_3... Done.\nXXX"
    sleep 1
} |whiptail --title "Yum Removal" --gauge "Please wait while installing" 6 60 0
```

Here, the key part is `echo -n "XXX\n<new percent>\n<new_gauge_text>\nXXX"`. The `XXX` string is used by whiptail to indicate modifications to the display.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but your script doesn't seem to run, it is stuck at zero percentage for 5-6 seconds and then exits.

Comment: what OS/version of whiptail are you using ? copying & pasting this code snippet on my machine works perfectly (whiptail 0.52.18 running on wsl - Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: I am running it in RHEL 6 with whiptail version : whiptail (newt): 0.52.11       then it stucks whereas i verified in RHEL 7 with whiptail version whiptail (newt): 0.52.15, there it works perfectly. But i need it for RHEL 6.